# Words ending in "m" in hexidecmial end up being corrupted by removal of carriage return

Tags: tcl

I can't seem to find a reasonable workaround, or fix on removing "0d" "\r" from a string without it not breaking the hexidemical string.

okay, I am feeding data to a variable from a HTML form.
The HTML page has three separate unique HTML text area fields and they are populated like so.

```
Type | Food | Flavour
Cold | Ice Cream | Mint
Warm | Pudding | Chocolate
```

Upon submission, this is then written to a text file in hexadecimal.

```
436f6c64 49636520437265616d 4d696e74
5761726d 50756464696e67 43686f636f6c61746520
```

Natively, due to the new line nature of the HTML textarea, when you post the form the textarea adds  carriage returns "CR" or "0d" (in hex) to the end of the line. As designed.

For example when the string "Ice Cream" is collected from the raw input and converted to hex: 
`Ice Cream` becomes 49636520437265616d**0d**
`Pudding` becomes 50756464696e67**0d** and so on.

So I remove this (0d), however next up is the writing to file. I have a loop that splits each entered values from the HTML page by new line "\n"

```
proc crystalEditor::save {} {
set i "0"
set formType [getFormValue type] ;#this contains the first textArea HTML element text #should be value: cold
set formFood [getFormValue food] ;#second textArea HTML element text #should be value: Ice Cream
set formFlavour [getFormValue flavour] ;#third textArea HTML element text #should be value: Mint

foreach formPost $formFood {
set foodType [2Hex [lindex [split $formType \n] $i]] ;#convert the whole entry to hex then
set foodFood [2Hex [lindex [split $formFood \n] $i]] ;#split the line by newline
set foodFlavour [2Hex [lindex [split $formFlavour \n] $i]] 
crystalEditor::hexWrite "$crystalEditor::myHexFiles/$fileName" "$foodType" "$foodFood" "$foodFlavour"
incr i
} ;#end foreach
crystalEditor::home [hex "$crystalEditor" "$crystalEditor::myHexFiles/$fileName"] ;#Load the HTML template with the hexFile
} ;#end procedure
```

This is what the procedure crystalEditor looks like.

```
proc crystalEditor::hexWrite {myPath foodType foodFood foodFlavour} {

set foodType [string trimright $foodType 0d] ;#remove \r from hex string
set foodFood [string trimright $foodFood 0d] ;#otherwise on load, 
set foodFlavour [string trimright $foodFlavour 0d]

set fp [open "$myPath" a]
puts $fp "$foodType $foodFood $foodFlavour"
close $fp
} ;#end procedure
```

The 2Hex procedure is of this:

```
proc 2Hex { text } { 
binary encode hex [encoding convertto utf-8 "$text"] 
} ;#end procedure
```

and the procedure for getting form values:

```
proc getFormValue {formName}
[ns_set get [ns_getform] $formName] ;#$formName is the formName in the HTML page.
} ;#end procedure
```

So, it works on any entry unless the word ends in "m".

The reason for this is that the letter "m" hexed is "6d" and because "0d" which represents \r (carriage return) is being stripped by the syntax

```
[string trimright $someValue 0d]
```

it also strips the hex decimal "d" from the the string, or hex string "Ice Cream" in this case.. I don't know why. I've tried many other ways but none of them work.

So **Ice Cream** (43 72 65 61 6d) becomes **Ice Crea** (43 72 65 61 6) but leaves the digit 6. Which is invalid for hex and throws a corruption if you try to parse the file.

I can come up with convoluted workarounds, but I am trying to avoid.
Essentially I just need to remove "\r" or "0d" from a string.

Also P.S: If I am writing text files with hex data, would it be wiser to save them as binary format?

Comment: What are the steps involved in transforming the HTML textarea string/value, to hex?  Because depending on what that process is, perhaps just trimming the string first is the simplest solution.

Comment: I'm running via webServer known as NaviServer. Which allows you to hook TCL in to live domain. domain.example/food would then execute the "food" procedure from the TCL script.  The procedure within the webserver is "[ns_set get [ns_getform] formName]" the raw data from the HTML form includes CR, so the only way to strip it is once its arrived in to the application. 2Hex { text } { binary encode hex [encoding convertto utf-8 "$text"] } would be the hex conversion code. Edit: Ah, it just tweaked what you meant.

Comment: Sadly not, its still removing the "m" from Ice Cream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use `trimright`, try:

```
regsub {0d$} $foodType {} foodType
```

This will remove the trailing '0d' rather than stripping
all '0' and all 'd' characters.

References: [regsub](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm), [re_syntax](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), [string](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: I would have decoded the hex and then trimright-ed that.